# Goal:i want to access object name and store it in a variable

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, api

Guys please help me i am stuck, I am trying to access this JSON with with `$.ajax()` , now here is my problem I want to show the object names on the table heading. I can able to access the last object's key/value pairs, but how can i access the object's name. here is my JSON file

```
[
    {
        "Person1": [{
            "test": {
                "name": "abhi",
                "age": "text"
            }
        },
        {
            "Person2": {
                "name": "akash",
                "age": "test-1"
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        "Test1": [{
            "text": {
                "name": "abhi",
                "age": "text"
            }
        },
        {
            "text-2": {
                "name": "akash",
                "age": "test-2"
            }
        }]
    }
]
```

I want something like this `Heading : Person1` and `Heading2 : test` in the browser.  I want to just store those `Person1` and `test` in a variable so that I can display in a table.

If you want full code I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax take a call back to get the result after the success request , you can try this for example :

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"your url here",
    methods:"your method here[GET|POST]",
   success(data){// this is the callback that called when the call succeeded

    console.log(data.Person1)  


          // you can use object destruction as well 

        let{Person1,Test1,Person2,text}=data
           console.log(Person1)
           console.log(Test1)
           console.log(text)

        }


    })
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want to parse the JSON data through ajax call.
Please Try the following with result from the ajax call:

```
list[0]
list[0]["Person1"]                   #{"test": { "name": "abhi","age": "text" }}
list[0]["Person1"]["test"]           #{ "name": "abhi","age": "text" }
list[0]["Person1"]["test"]["name"]   #abhi
```

Make sure to provide more data regarding your problem and what you have tried. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you have the json as an objectm otherwize use JSON.parse to get the array.

```
var words = json.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0]);
```

This should get you a list of the property names of the first level objects in the array.

Explanation:

What you have is an array of objects with one property each that in turn contains more data.

What thee code does is it maps over the array, uses the Object.keys to get all property keys of the objects and then pick the first one.

This will not find multiple properties from the objects and will fail if you have empty objects.

Is this what you was looking for?